# Git Rebase introducing a merge commit

Tags: git

I have the following situation:

1. Branch A
2. Branch B which is created from Branch A say as commit `CommitInitialA`
3. I make a few commits on Branch B say `CommitB1`<-`CommitB2`
4. Branch A gets some commits in parallel say `CommitA1`<-`CommitA2`
5. I run git rebase so that branch B has a linear history `CommitInitialA`<-`CommitA1`<-`CommitA2`<-`CommitB1`<-`CommitB2`
6. Now, in future, Branch B gets new commit say `CommitB3` and in parallel Branch A get new commit `CommitA3`

At this point when I try to rebase branch B again on branch A, I see that there is a merge commit in Branch B from `CommitInitialA` instead of a linear history.

How should I use rebase the second time so that I don't get a merge commit but instead a linear history?

Essentially after 2nd rebase after Step 6 above, I want 
`CommitInitialA`<-`CommitA1`<-`CommitA2`<-`CommitA3`<-`CommitB1`<-`CommitB2`<-`CommitB3`

Comment: Was there a merge conflict while rebasing?

Comment: @AkshayKumar: no

Comment: You may cherry-pick the last commit to the branch ... it will be linear.

Comment: Can you list all the commands executed on `BranchA` and `BranchB`?  As far as I know, no version of the `git rebase` command should create a merge commit.

Comment: Unless you use `git rebase -p` or the newfangled (well, not quite that new any more) `git rebase -r`, rebase never *makes* merges and always *strips* merges as it copies commits. But be aware that *branch names* are essentially meaningless; all that matters in a Git repository are the commits themselves. Branch names just let you *find* the commits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this and see that there is no issue if no conflict :

```
git init
git checkout -b branchA
touch inita testb1 testb2 testb3 testa1 testa2 testa3
git add inita
git commit -m "commitInitialA"
git checkout -b branchB
git add testb1
git commit -m "commitB1"
git add testb2
git commit -m "commitB2"
git checkout branchA
git add testa1
git commit -m "commitA1"
git add testa2
git commit -m "commitA2"
```

At this point :

[image]

First rebase :

```
git checkout branchB
git rebase branchA
```

[image]

Other commits :

```
git add testb3
git commit -m "commitB3"
git checkout branchA
git add testa3
git commit -m "commitA3"
```

At this point :

[image]

Second rebase :

```
git checkout branchB
git rebase branchA
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

suppose `A` is master branch
and `B` is create from branch `A` at first time both have same commit id suppose

```
A = `CommitA1`
B = `CommitB1`
```

now, changes in both branch so so both have one more commit

A is moved to `CommitA2` and B is moved to `CommitB2`

before merging B branch into A branch we need to rebase A branch with latest pull in branch B

So B branch will have below lines of commit

```
CommitB2 - your recent commit of branch B on the top
CommitB1 - from current brnanch B2
CommitA2 -from branch A
CommitA1 - from branch A
```

now if you are not merging B branch to A branch and continue working on that

B branch will move to another commit which is having hash id `CommitB3`
A is also having some commit like `CommitA3`

B is already having commits before added by branch A so git pull will tries to merge that commit due to duplication of commits code in branch B, to resolve that.

when you are again rebasing 
it shows message like

and have 2 and 2 different commits each, respectively

on branch B instead of taking `pull`, you need to push your commit forcefully to your branch, `git pull` gives you the commits which are already having in branch B due to before rebase, there might be changes of merge commits.

```
git push --force
```